# How to Make Bootstrap 3 Button Text Responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [<kbd>This Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/egt32eon/) and let me know how I can make only the text inside the buttons responsive to the size of the button?

```
<div class="container"><div class="well">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Make Me Responsive!</button>
</div></div>
```

As you can see from the demo the buttons test font size stays same as the initial times on resizing the windows. Can you please let  me know how I can update id without using the body element?

Thanks,

Comment: Wait so basically you are asking how to resize the text inside the button as you increase the width of the page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/egt32eon/4/

Comment: Thanks Christina but I wouldn't like to use the word-wrap property. Is there any other way to change the font size on resize? using CSS only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you could use CSS `@media` queries to achieve the result, you could also use `vw` [Viewport-percentage](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) lengths in order to specify the `font-size` based on the width of the viewport:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/egt32eon/5/)**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block responsive-width">
    Make Me Responsive!
</button>
```

```css
.responsive-width {
    font-size: 3vw;
}
```

> **[5.1.2 Viewport-percentage lengths: the vw, vh, vmin, vmax units](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)**
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly. However,
>   when the value of overflow on the root element is auto, any scroll
>   bars are assumed not to exist. Note that the initial containing
>   block’s size is affected by the presence of scrollbars on the
>   viewport.
>
> **[vw unit](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#vw)**
>   Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.

It's worth noting that `vw` unit [is supported in the modern web browsers](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) (including IE9+).

Answer (score 3):

I tried a different solution and it worked. I share it here:

```
  <button type="button" class="enviaPedido btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    <span class="visible-xs-block">Pedido</span>
    <span class="hidden-xs">Convertir en pedido</span>
  </button>
```